# PyCharm Updating python interpreter takes too long ( Setup downloading volume file ... )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2023.2.3 to work on a project using a remote python interpreter.

On selecting the remote python interpreter, the IDE continues showing me the following error forever :

[image]

There are no issues in transferring files to/from the remote server using ssh/rsync.

I would normally expect PyCharm to take a little time to update the python interpreter and then I can resume my work.

How can I debug this issue further and solve it ?

Comment: I just experienced the very same issue. As far as I know, the problem is that PcCharm is copying your local files to a tmp folder, which you define when setting up the ssh interpreter. Do you have any big files in your local folder? For me, excluding some folders / files of my local folder solved the issue.